# Get the class name using class attributes

Tags: c#

I'm create the class

```
public class MarkerAttribute : Attribute
{

}
```

and set this attribute in MyTestClass

```
[Marker]
public class MyTestsClass
{

}
```

How can I receive the names of all classes which have this attribute in my project?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean at runtime, by reflection, or do you mean searching in IDE tools etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the types that have the attribute using reflection like this:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class MarkerAttribute : Attribute {
}

[Marker]
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()) {
            foreach (Attribute attribute in type.GetCustomAttributes()) {
                MarkerAttribute markerAttribute = attribute as MarkerAttribute;
                if (markerAttribute != null) {
                    Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```